# Solving the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+3y+y^2}{x+2xy}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my ODE course, I've stumbled upon the following ODE whose RHS is a rational function.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+3y+y^2}{x+2xy}.$$

It seems that the question is insinuating that we can solve using elementary tools. The first thing I thought is seeing if we get an exact form. Letting $N=x+2xy$ and $M=-(2x+3y+y^2)$ we have that

$$M_y=-3-2y=-2-(1+2y)=-2-N_x$$

So the form $Mdx+Ndy$ is not exact. If I want to make it exact by multiplying by an integrating factor $\mu$, then I must solve the PDE
$$\mu_yM+\mu M_y=\mu_xN+\mu N_x=\mu_xN+\mu(-M_y-2)$$
But it doesn't seem I can get much from this. Am I missing some obvious trick?

***Only hints, no full answers please!***

---

I realized I made a mistake with the problem in fact the equation is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\color{red}{3}x+\color{red}{2}y+y^2}{x+2xy}.$$

This means that
$$M_y=-2-2y=-2(1+y)=-2N_x.$$

But still that doesn't help. In any case, I will be interested in an answer to any of these equations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann fixed the typos. But what to do next?

Comment: You made a sign error, the form $Mdx+Ndy=0$ gives $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{M}{N}$. Then some terms cancel in the PDE, but if that helps...

Comment: Some shortening of the equation results from setting $x=u^2$, $v=2y+1$, then $w=uv$, but that does not lead to an obvious solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks you for the remark. Please check important edit to answer.

Comment: No solution in terms of elementary function exists according to some online calculators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a system out of it to add some flexibility
\begin{align}
\dot x&=x(1+2y),& x(0)&=x_0\\
\dot y&=-(3x+2y+y^2),& y(0)&=y_0.
\end{align}
Then the second equation looks like Riccati, so set $y=\frac{\dot v}{v}$, $\dot v(0)=y_0v_0$, to get
$$
\frac{\ddot v}{v}=-3x-2\frac{\dot v}{v}
$$
This then gives the new system
\begin{align}
\dot x v-2x\dot v-xv&=0 ,
\\
\ddot v+2\dot v+3xv&=0 .
\end{align}
The first equation integrates to $x=Ce^tv^2$, $x_0=Cv_0^2$ (for instance select $v_0$ so that $C=\pm1$), so that the second equation becomes
$$
\ddot v+2\dot v+3Ce^tv^3=0 .
$$
Set
\begin{align}
w&=e^{t/2}v,& w_0&=v_0, 
\\
\dot w&=e^{t/2}(\dot v+v/2),& \dot w(0)&=\dot v_0+v_0/2, 
\\
\ddot w&=e^{t/2}(\ddot v+\dot v+v/4),
\end{align}
so that
$$
\ddot w+\dot w=e^{t/2}(\ddot v+2\dot v+3v/4)=\frac34w-3Cw^3
$$
This in general has no closed solution, but can be analyzed as similar to a mechanical system with the force on the right side and friction coefficient $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The last equation $\ddot{w}+\dot{w}-\frac{3}{4}w=-3Cw^3$ is called semi-linear right? I find this weird that this question is asked in an elementary course. Probably some typo somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps the $3x$ in the numerator should have been a constant $-3$, absorbing also the minus sign, so that it factors as $(3+y)(-1+y)$, and the equation becomes separable with an easy enough partial fraction decomposition. In such cases of doubt an image of the equation would help (keep size and resolution small).